# Object based Joomla API method for duplication check

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api

I need to check one value in database which is duplicated or not. I don't know in Joomla object based method is available for this check. I used object based Joomla api method for insert and update database using the below code

```
$this->_db->insertObject($table,object);
```

But I need to know the Joomla object based method available for duplication check.

Kindly assist. I am new to the Joomla platform.

Comment: This may be helpful: [Insert query with ignore of duplicates (without key)](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22966/12352) or maybe: [Check if INSERT query was successful or failed because of a duplicate UNIQUE KEY](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22950/12352)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this without first doing a look up to check if the value already exists in the db before inserting.

The "check" that Joomla does is for the primary key only - so it cannot insert if the primary key is duplicated.

The correct way is to create a table class that extends JTable and then implement the bind/check/save methods of that with your additional data integrity logic, or one step up in the model apply your business logic there see [The JTable Class](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JTable.html) - see also [How to use the JTable Class](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_JTable_class)