# Insert query with ignore of duplicates (without key)

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, jdatabase

I have a query:

```
$query_add_analogue
  ->insert($db->quoteName('#__parts_analogues'))
  ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
  ->values($value);
$db->setQuery($query_add_analogue);
$db->execute();
```

The table "#_parts_analogues" have two columns - "original_id" and "analogue_id".

I need to ignore the insert function, when the pair of values already exist in table. There is no primary key in table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're using MySQL, you can create an unique index over your columns `original_id` and `analogue_id`.

Then use a raw query like:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO ' . $db->quoteName('#__parts_analogues') VALUES ("your", "values");
$db->setQuery($query)->execute();
```

It works like an insert, but does not return an error.

Keep in mind that working without an index can lead to serious performance issues.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain what is "unique index over columns"? I can't understand =(

Comment: @christian if you see, you have not used actual OO query here, is there any way to achieve this with complete OO query.

Comment: @Anant without performing a `str_replace()` this is as "OO" as it can get because Joomla's `insert()` method does not accommodate `IGNORE`.

Answer (score 1):

Option #1 - the clean way (my recommended approach)

Call this query from phpMyAdmin to permanently establish the two columns as `UNIQUE KEYS`. (You will need to replace the `#_` prefix with your private prefix string.)

```
ALTER TABLE `#__parts_analogues` ADD UNIQUE KEY(original_id, analogue_id)
```

Then whenever you wish to throw new rows into the table, you can use a `INSERT IGNORE INTO` query to avoid receiving those syntax errors.  This adjustment is applied inside the `setQuery()` call.

Here is how I would write the OO code:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
try {
    $insert_query = $db->getQuery(true)
                       ->insert("#__parts_analogues")
                       ->columns("original_id, analogue_id")
                       ->values($value); // I'm not sure if you are delivering a string, 1-dim array, or multi-dim array

    $db->setQuery(preg_replace('~INSERT \K~', 'IGNORE ', $insert_query, 1));    // add IGNORE after first occurring `INSERT ` in query
    $db->execute();
    echo $db->getAffectedRows() , " row(s) inserted into parts_analogues table";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo  "Syntax Error"; // . " & Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I'm not sure if `$value` is a comma-separated string, a one-dimensional array containing two elements, or a multi-dimensional array containing sets of 2-element subarrays.  If these `id` values are integers and coming from an external source, you should cast each `id` as `(int)` before feeding to the query for security reasons.  Here's some relevant literature:

- https://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase#Inserting_a_Record
- https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseQuery.html#method_values
- https://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines#Constructing_SQL_queries

I should also point out that there is *technically* a possibility of making unintended multiple replacements within the query while using `str_replace()`. For this reason, I am using `preg_replace()` with a replacement limit of 1 for peace of mind.

Another note: Joomla puts `\r\n` (or just `\n` depending on your operating system) at the start of the query; `var_dump($db)` after `setQuery()` to see.  For this reason, my pattern does not use `~^INSERT ~`, but I could just as easily use `~^\sINSERT~` or `~^\RINSERT ~` to anchor the pattern to the start of the string.

---

Option #2 - which IMO is the less elegant way because it requires two round trips to the database.

Basically, you would run a [SELECT COUNT(*)](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#Single_Value_Result) query with a `WHERE` clause that searches for matches using your `$values` data to determine if the pair of values exists in the table, then you call an `INSERT` query when it is unique.  *note, you can use two `where()` method calls, but I don't prefer that style because it is too much of a departure from raw sql syntax.  You could also hardcode the `AND` and write a single string, but I was trying to get the whole code block to fit the available width on this page.

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
try {
    $select_query = $db->getQuery(true)
                       ->select("COUNT(*)")
                       ->from("#__parts_analogues")
                       ->where(
                           array(
                             "original_id = " . (int)$original_id),
                             "analogue_id = " . (int)$analogue_id)
                           )
                         )
                       ->setLimit(1);

    $db->setQuery($select_query);
    if (!$db->loadResult()) {
        // if count is 0 (false-y) that means the values are unique
        $insert_query = $db->getQuery(true)
                           ->insert("#__parts_analogues")
                           ->columns("original_id, analogue_id")
                           ->values((int)$original_id . "," . (int)$analogue_id);

        $db->setQuery($insert_query);
        $db->execute();
        echo "Row Added";
    } else {
        echo "Non-unique Values";
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo  "Syntax Error"; // . " & Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I like option 2 as a solution on this particular question, even if it is two rounds on database.

Comment: What's not to like about the first?

Comment: In your first solution I still do not like that you made both fields unique. Your second solution however really answer the original problem, so that is actually the correct solution.

Comment: It is my understanding that the pair of columns logically needs to be unique. 
 Setting up a "fit-for-purpose" database table structure enables refined querying processes for all future interactions (code size is halved in this case). I don't understand how this detracts, but you are free to like whatever you like.  Thanks for the vote.

Comment: Of course, we had a difference in understanding of the original problem of this question, but it does not matter. I can learn a lot from your well worked out query examples and that's what really matters for me.

Comment: In the context of the question (columns with ids), solution one is OK, but generally, its an extremely bad idea. If for any reason, your data, or a sub-query contains the text 'INSERT' then the str_replace will modify data unexpectedly. I think the accepted answer where the SQL is directly built, is probably the best solution. Possibly, you could alter to a 'preg_replace' and match only 'INSERT's at the beginning of the query.

Comment: @Dom I don't disagree with you, this is why I said: _I should also point out that there is technically a possibility of making unintended multiple replacements within the query while using `str_replace()`_ in my answer.  Since my focus is to help the future researchers as well as the OP, I'll take a moment to remove the less robust `str_replace()` call.

Comment: @Dom I don't know if the new downvote on this answer is from you, but if it is I'd like to understand why it is necessary.  Afterall, I have agreed with your sentiment and edited my answer to remove the `str_replace()` from my php snippet.  This answer will do no harm to researchers, works as required and should be considered best practice (because it will implement Joomla's query building methods as much as possible). Adherence to these methods throughout a project will make the project more portable when being implemented with different database types.

Comment: I've downvoted your answer because using any form of string manipulation on source code (the query) is a bad idea as it makes the code much harder for someone else to understand. If you're going to sacrifice code clarity, then you need a very good reason. Your justification is portability, but the 'IGNORE' keyword is not portable between databases. So you've gained nothing but made the code much harder to understand. Your second answer is arguably better than the accepted solution, as its agnostic of the underlying database, even if it does incur two trips to the database.

Answer (score 1):

I give a solution on this just for the new readers who may are looking for solution on this kind of problems. You cannot really solve this problem with Joomla query methods. As it was given above, a simple MySQL query like "INSERT IGNORE INTO" should work but it is not always the right solution. Instead, the "INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" MySql query works. Why? Because if a record already exists, then it will be just updated (probably with the same record or with an updated record with the same ids and unique fields, so it is not a problem), if the record does not exist, then it will be created, inserted as a new record in the table.

First, understanding this particular problem in the original question (in this problem you want to insert or update a pair of keys into the table), you should not make the two columns in the table UNIQUE - "original_id" and "analogue_id". Because if you make them unique then you cannot insert again a pair of new keys where one of the keys is the same as the earlier inserted key of the pair. For example you earlier inserted a pair of keys like original_id = 1 and analogue_id = 1, and now you try to insert a new pair like original_id = 1 and analogue_id = 2. If these keys are both UNIQUE in the table you will not be able to insert the second pair as new pair and at the same time you will not want to update them either.

So what I would do is I would generate (in my code) a real UNIQUE key from the original_id and analogue_id keys and I would insert them together with the generated Unique key into the table. And then when I am updating the table with new data or inserting new data in the table I would use for example:

```
$my_unique_key = $original_id . $analogue_id . "something_to_make_it_more_unique";

$myTableItems = new stdClass();

// You can put all of the data items into the $myTableItems object
// if you have many of these data
// I will not do that here due to time saving

// and in foreach loop

foreach ($myTableItems as $item) {

  $fields = array($db->quoteName('myunique_key') . ' = ' . $db->quote($item->my_unique_key),
            $db->quoteName('original_id') . ' = ' . $db->quote($item->original_id),
            $db->quoteName('analogue_id') . ' = ' . $db->quote($item->analogue_id));

  $values = array($item->my_unique_key, $item->original_id, $item->analogue_id);

  $query = "INSERT INTO #__mytable (myunique_key, original_id, analogue_id) VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $values) . "')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" . implode(", ", $fields);

  $db->setQuery($query)->execute();
  }
```

And if you want to just insert the new records and you do not want to update the old records then you can use the INSERT IGNORE INTO query like this:

```
$query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO #__mytable (myunique_key, original_id, analogue_id) VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $values) . "')";
```

Simple reference on these Sql queries is for example [here](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/).

Comment: I feel that this `ON DUPLICATE` is the right solution to a different question.  Here the OP states clearly that if the row is a duplicate (based on the column criteria), then nothing should be done.  If your query is executed with the same outcome, then the database row will be overwritten with the pre-existing value(s) and make success/aff_rows harder to determine than the alternative.  This is why I would not recommend `ON DUPLICATE`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, many times you do not want to update the existing data in the table, then the INSERT IGNORE query works the best. I update my message with that query. However, In your long description the $db->setQuery(str_replace("INSERT", "INSERT IGNORE", $insert_query)); does not work, you cannot do it that way. The query will not be changed to INSERT IGNORE from INSERT that way. (I have checked that). Have you used that and it worked?

Comment: Yes, it does work.  I test all of my queries before posting because I would hate to give false information.  (And there are other posters that have used the same approach on this site)  That said, it is vulnerable to "over-replacing" in the fringe case where you have a value that contains the word `INSERT`.  I could use regex to ensure only the first `INSERT` is replaced, but I didn't go down that rabbit hole.

Comment: I'll double check now.

Comment: Ohh, then I will check that again, I do not know why it was not working for me... Thank you for your comments!

Comment: Okay, here is the tricky part...  I was right, the `IGNORE` is applied to the query as desired, BUT if you call `$query->dump()` you don't _see_ the `IGNORE` substring in the query.  This is deceiving.  If I remove the replacement call, the query produces the Duplicate Entry error -- so this confirms that `IGNORE` is present and operating as intended.

Comment: First, for me it also looked like a good, nice solution (that is why I checked that) but anyway it helped me in the question, even if it was not working, thank you! (You never know what could help others :) )

Comment: I wonder why it didn't work for you.  Do you have a snippet that I can look at? Maybe I can spot something.

Comment: Then I will really check that again for myself :) (and will get back to you with the results on this)...

Comment: To explain what's weird about the replacement task, `$insert_query` is originally declared as an object, but when it is used inside the `str_replace()` call, it is degraded to a string and loses all of the beautiful features that were originally built for it -- so `$insert_query->dump()` is not longer accessible.  If you overwrite `$insert_query` with the result from `str_replace()` and echo it, then the `IGNORE` keyword is presented.

Comment: Beside the query ran to error for me on inserts, the $query->dump() also did not show the IGNORE part of the query for me (as you also wrote). So this mislead me too. But now I printed out $db (after the string replace call) and the IGNORE part of the query is really presented. Really weird. I am checking it further why it does not insert my new records then...

Comment: Quite right, `var_dump($db);` does show the `IGNORE` keyword.

Comment: I am sorry for the short break. I have to confirm that your solution is working. So apologize me for saying earlier that it's not working. I just tried again, I double checked everything in my code (found the bug) and the query is executed and works like it should.
So: $db->setQuery(str_replace("INSERT", "INSERT IGNORE", $insert_query));
does work! Even if we cannot see the IGNORE keyword when we dump the query.

Comment: So I will update my description on this part giving you a credit for this!

Comment: If you are planning to edit your answer and add redundant information (that already exists in my answer), please don't.  That would be useless page bloat.

Comment: My opinion is that peer review is not bloating a page like this, but it can help other readers to make sure that a given code is useful and works and also help understanding problems and solutions better...

Answer (score 0):

After some feedback from [@Dom](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/21155/insert-query-with-ignore-of-duplicates-without-key/22966#comment35776_22966), I think I mostly agree that the other existing answers up to this point are providing hackish techniques on the query which will either:

1. be less portable
2. lead to inconsistent query building techniques throughout a single project
3. be vulnerable to race conditions
4. and/or diminish script readability

Some suggested techniques advise to adjust the query (my earlier answer included) to enjoy the features of a limited number of database types.  This means that if/when you want to switch your project to another database, your code will break because the keyword/technique is not available.

More generally, I think it is best practice to fully utilise Joomla's query building helper methods ...until absolutely necessary to circumvent them.

And finally, making two trips to a database (one to check if unique identifiers exist and a second to insert when missing) is not a 100% reliable solution because there is *technically* the potential that a concurrent query write can occur on the target row in the moment between the first and the second query executing.  (Not very likely, but possible)

**TL;DR**

Just make your identifying columns unique:

```
ALTER TABLE `#__parts_analogues` ADD UNIQUE KEY(original_id, analogue_id)
```

Then execute your insert query normally, but catch the error so that there are never any unexpected interruptions to your application.

```
$query_add_analogue
  ->insert($db->quoteName('#__parts_analogues'))
  ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
  ->values($value);
$db->setQuery($query_add_analogue);
try {
    $db->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // do nothing
}
```

I don't know if other databases have a different error number for Duplicate Key errors (anyone is welcome to educate me), but in MySQL it is specifically `1062`, so you could even specify which error to ignore and which ones you actually want to acknowledge (in case your query might fail in a different way).

```
try {
    $db->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() == 1062) {
        // do nothing with duplicate key failure
    } else {
        // log the error or present to screen with enqueueMessage or whatever
    }
}
```

P.S. You might want to research `$db->insertObject()` to execute the insert as a means of a more concise coding technique.