# How can I insert email address to database who sent an email via contact form?

Tags: joomla-3.6

I'm trying to save email addresses to database when a customer send an email via contact form. I put the insert query into the `_sendEmail` function, but when I send an email, it didn't insert the address. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you please share the code for your full query so we can look through it?

Comment: Also, please clarify how exactly it is not working.  Is there an error generated?  If so, we'd like to know the error message.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't modify core files. Create a contact plugin with `onSubmitContact` event. Basic example to catch unique emails:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;

class PlgContactEmails extends CMSPlugin
{
    public function onSubmitContact(&$contact, &$data)
    {
        if (empty($data['contact_email']))
        {
            return;
        }

        $db = JFactory::getDbo();

        $query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select('COUNT(*)')
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__plg_contact_emails'))
            ->where($db->quoteName('email') . ' = ' . $db->quote($data['contact_email']));

        if ($db->setQuery($query)->loadResult())
        {
            return;
        }

        $query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->insert($db->quoteName('#__plg_contact_emails'))
            ->columns($db->quoteName('email'))
            ->values($db->quote($data['contact_email']));

        $db->setQuery($query)->execute();
    }
}
```

Note, you have to create a SQL installation script for creating custom database table and add it to plugin's manifest file.

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Using_the_Database

Answer (score 1):

To expand/refine Sharky's answer, you can set up your new/basic database table with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__plg_contact_emails` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

By setting `email` as a UNIQUE key, you can streamline the plugin's querying process and ensure that your table only contains unique email addresses.

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;

class PlgContactEmails extends CMSPlugin
{
    public function onSubmitContact(&$contact, &$data)
    {
        if (!empty($data['contact_email']) && filter_var($data['contact_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))  // in case validation is necessary
        {
            $db = JFactory::getDBO();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                        ->insert("#__plg_contact_emails")
                        ->columns("email")
                        ->values($db->q($data['contact_email']));
            $db->setQuery(preg_replace('~INSERT \K~', 'IGNORE ', $query, 1));    // add IGNORE to avoid duplicate entry error
            $db->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a related post where I explain the effect and benefits of my single query snippet: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22966/12352

---

If you can't or don't want to hack at the built query with `IGNORE`, you can convert mysql errors to exceptions and either ignore them or handle them specifically:

```
if (!empty($data['contact_email']) && filter_var($data['contact_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))  // in case validation is necessary
{
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->insert("#__plg_contact_emails")
        ->values("null, " . $db->q($data['contact_email']));  // without columns() call
    $db->setQuery($query);
    try
    {
        $db->execute();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        // do nothing or whatever you like
        if ($e->getCode() == 1062)
        {
            // JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("Duplicate Entry", 'notice');
        }
        else
        {
            // JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("Syntax Error", 'error');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This results in `INSERT IGNOREINTO` for me (using MariaDB 10.1). Also, `INSERT IGNORE` is not supported on PostgreSQL, I think.

Comment: Must not be `\r\n` at the front of the query.  Probably only `\n`.  I've never used PostgreSQL or MariaDB.  `preg_replace('~INSERT \K~', 'IGNORE ', $query, 1)` should work everywhere.

Comment: Doesn't work yet. The inconsistency is between different operating systems. Original code works on Windows but not on Linux. So line endings could indeed be the issue. Could use `strpos()` in this case: `substr_replace($query, ' IGNORE', strpos($query, 'INSERT') + 6, 0)`.